# How to resolve StackOverflow/AccessViolation Exception in Entity Framework with enormous entity >= 775 properties?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

We have an enormous entity with 811 properties.

We generate views dynamically at runtime, which completes successfully.

We are testing by a simple query for all records all columns.

From trial and error we discovered if the property count is less than 775, the query returns no problem. If >= 755 it causes either an AccessViolation exception or StackOverflow Exception, like:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFramework.dll`

It seems we have hit a ceiling for entity size. Because the exception appears to be from within EntityFramework core, it's hard to debug further.

Is this a known limitation and is there anything we can do to work around it?

Exception details:
[image: Exception details]

**EDIT**

The underlying database is SQL, and here is the query (column names redacted as this is company internals)

```
[18:18:06 INF] Executed DbCommand (112ms) [Parameters=[@__TypedProperty_1='?' (DbType = Int32), @__TypedProperty_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='"Text"', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT TOP(@__TypedProperty_1) [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...], [t].[column_...]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@__TypedProperty_0) [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...], [p].[column_...]
    FROM [dbo].[table_...] AS [p]
    ORDER BY [p].[column_...]
) AS [t]
ORDER BY [t].[column_...]
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
```

Comment: What is the underlying database?

Comment: Better to create reproducible sample and post issue to EF Core github repository. StackOverflow exception is not that you should expect from EF Core. Also you can post sample of the query, maybe I can estimate complexity or how simplify it.

Comment: @Eldar underlying database is tSQL

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Have added the query sample to the question. The query is pretty simple I think.

Comment: Show LINQ query.

Comment: Just to get the obvious out of the way, in those extra properties I assume you don't cause that StackOverflow yourself, by having `int MyProperty { get => MyProperty; set => MyProperty=value; }` (typo: property instead of backingfield)?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing No, definitely not doing that. All properties on the entity definition are very simple, like `public string Description { get; set; }` or `public virtual PromotionLevel PromotionLevel { get; set; }`

Comment: Need proper repro to help here.

Comment: @ErikEJ yeah, fair enough. Will see what I can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by turning off change tracking in our `DbContext`.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            ...
            .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
    }
}
```

Our endpoint is intended to be readonly anyway.